# Hover doesn't work on button element

Tags: css, html, hover

Hopefully this will be an easy thing to fix, but I have tried searching for an answer and nothing seems to fit.

I'm trying to make a hover effect on a button:

```
button {
min-width: 20vw;
max-width: 40vw;
border: none;
color: white;
font-size: 1.5vw;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: blue;
border-radius: 20px;
transition: 0.4s;
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
.button:hover {
color: black;
background-color: lightcyan;
}
```

When I test this in a browser (vivaldi & edge) nothing changes. The test site is http://wyrdling.com/skulpturjagt by the way.

PS. I tried using the chrome developer tool, but I'm too much of a newb to figure out how to read it XD

Comment: It's probably beacuse you use the class `.button`, try to remove the dot `.` so go for : `button:hover { your style }` or if u want to have it as class just add dot `.` to the `button` style and attach it to the element in your html. I have posted an anwser for you to show how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless its a typo in your question, you use `.button:hover`. That will apply to elements with a class of `hover`. Swap it to `button:hover`

Comment: Upvoting as there are unnecessary downvotes. This user spent his 'time' to find the error, no matter how simple/silly it is. So I think we should respect that effort. And not every one would be an expert in the beginning so let's show some respect to new programmers too when they as a question, as we all (or at least most of us) have made these mistakes in the initial programming days. Thank you.

Comment: @GibinEalias downvotes are not for the Person who done the effort ... if you look to the question can you tell me how this question can help future users ? is this question a good ressource for this website ? such simple issue deserve to be popular and upvoted ? ... I don't think so simply because `this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.`

Comment: @TemaniAfif if people in the future make the same silly little mistake of using a class of button instead of the button tag then yes, this answer is useful as its a simple answer to a simple issue

Comment: @mast3rd3mon no, people should first Search about the issue and read documentation to understand the difference between class and tag

Comment: @TemaniAfif granted, they should, but its now just another resource for people who made the same mistake

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Totally agree to your point that such questions can't be considered as good resources and adds almost no value to the website. But thinking from the OP's perspective, he/she is having an issue and is incapable of solving it and seeks help. In that case, I'm unsure how its fare to demotivate them by downvoting their questions and also the answers. Instead, supporting them will give them a welcoming atmosphere which could make them better users in future. Personally, I feel users, each single one, are important than the website, because without them the site is nothing.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some example plunkers.

Example 1:

```css
button {
min-width: 20vw;
max-width: 40vw;
border: none;
color: white;
font-size: 1.5vw;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: blue;
border-radius: 20px;
transition: 0.4s;
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
button:hover {
color: black;
background-color: lightcyan;
}
```

```html
<button>My button.</button>
```

Example 2 :

```css
.button {
min-width: 20vw;
max-width: 40vw;
border: none;
color: white;
font-size: 1.5vw;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: blue;
border-radius: 20px;
transition: 0.4s;
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
.button:hover {
color: black;
background-color: lightcyan;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">My button</button>
```